# Updating the Mobility gem

Tags: mobility

I would like to update the mobility gem.

Are there any known issues/needed steps when updating from v0.1.10 to v0.3.6 or can it be updated without any further steps needed?

Comment: Check out the [changelog](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: not the right place to ask this question..please refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Abhinay https://github.com/shioyama/mobility/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Stefan unfortunately no notes if breaking changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no major breaking changes between v0.1 and v0.3. You should be able to update right up to v0.4 (recently released), but of course it's always best to have a set of specs testing your application when upgrading any gem.